# How to convert frames from directory to video without adding the first frame every fps in Python?

Tags: python

I am fairly new to this platform. I will do my best to be clear as possible. My goal is to convert frames from my directory into a video. For some reason, it is including the first frame in every 15 fps. Here is my code below:

```
import cv2
import glob
from pathlib import Path

def play_frames(frames_dir, fps, output_video_path):
    # Get the list of frames in the directory
    frames = sorted(glob.glob(str(frames_dir / '*.png')))

    # Read the first frame to get the width and height
    frame = cv2.imread(frames[0])
    height, width, _ = frame.shape

    # Create the video writer object
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
    video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(output_video_path, fourcc, fps, (width, height))

    for frame_path in frames:
        # Read the frame
        frame = cv2.imread(frame_path)

        # Display the frame
        cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
        cv2.waitKey(int(1000 / fps))

        # Write the frame to the video
        video_writer.write(frame)

    # Release the video writer
    video_writer.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Directory path
frames_dir = Path('./detected_objects')
fps = 15
output_video_path = 'vid2output.mp4'

# Play the frames and save as video
play_frames(frames_dir, fps, output_video_path)
```

I have tried countless of codes here, but all the codes (that I have tried) keeps adding the first frame in every fps. What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to convert images to video without adding the first frame in every fps? (I have checked my frames in the directory, and they are all in the correct sequence.)

I appreciate everyone's help and happy to provide more information!

Update:
I added resolution size to the code, but the first frame keeps showing up every fps.

```
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path

def play_frames(frames_dir, fps, output_video_path):
    # Get the list of frames in the directory
    frames = sorted(glob.glob(str(frames_dir / '*.png')))

    # Read the first frame to get the width and height
    frame = cv2.imread(frames[0])
    height, width, _ = frame.shape

    # Calculate the maximum width and height among all frames
    max_width = width
    max_height = height

    for frame_path in frames[1:]:
        # Read each frame to get its dimensions
        frame = cv2.imread(frame_path)
        height, width, _ = frame.shape

        # Update the maximum width and height if necessary
        max_width = max(max_width, width)
        max_height = max(max_height, height)

    # Create the video writer object
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
    video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(output_video_path, fourcc, fps, (max_width, max_height))

    # Resize and pad each frame before writing to the video
    for frame_path in frames:
        frame = cv2.imread(frame_path)

        # Resize the frame to the maximum dimensions
        resized_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (max_width, max_height))

        # Write the resized frame to the video
        video_writer.write(resized_frame)

    # Release the video writer
    video_writer.release()

# Directory path
frames_dir = Path('./detected_objects')
fps = 15
output_video_path = 'vid1output.mp4'

# Play the frames and save as video
play_frames(frames_dir, fps, output_video_path)
```

Comment: I've run your code and it seems to work as intended, images in the folder get correctly added to the mp4 in the correct order and no additional first frame is added. So, some questions: What OS are you in? Do the file names have any special character? If you try to debug the code, does the "frames" object have correctly all the files in the correct order?

Comment: Are the `frames` sorted as you expected? Note that file viewers like Explorer have a different sorting algorithm than the `sorted` function. Also, does the number of frames in the resulting video match the number of images? In other words, is the first frame "added" or "inserted"? And lastly, is it exactly the first frame? For instance, if you make the first frame a bright red image, does it appear repeatedly?

Comment: I am running on my code on Pycharm on my Windows laptop. The file names do not have special characters. It is sorted the way I need them to be, on both Pycharm and on Explorer. Yes, it is exactly the first (and only) frame that appears repeatedly.

Comment: Does the problem persist if you try with other images? I'm in the same setup, Pycharm + Windows. Just downloaded an explosion animation, seems to work fine with no repeated frames, maybe try with different ones to see if it persists. Are you using the default video viewer from Windows? Is your system in a language different from English?

Comment: Additional question: are all the images in your folder exactly the same size than the first frame? Else the codec will fail to visualise it properly (and could cause the issue)

Comment: @AnilCh The problem does persist in other videos as well. I do use the default video viewer (it downloads the video file for me to click on and view on a separate window). The system is in English. The images' size range from 4-4.5 MB.

Comment: @kora_num14 I meant the resolution. They all must be the same width and height. If they're not you have to fill the sides for them to visualise properly.

Comment: I have now included resolution size on here. The first frame keeps showing up every fps.

Comment: Can you post input data and sample output (generated from exactly that input) reflecting the problem somewhere? We can't see this when we run it ourselves, but none of us have your data.

Comment: I have updated with the input images and the output video. @CharlesDuffy

Comment: It's hanging trying to load the list of images for me, but one thing I notice is that the image names aren't padded. If you have 100 images, the first one should be `001.png`, not `1.png` -- if you have 1000, the first one should be `0001.png`; if you don't do that, then the system thinks that 2 comes after 19 because it's sorting as strings instead of as numbers.

Comment: BTW, thank you for providing the input files -- couldn't have figured it out without seeing their names!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sorted()`, when given a list of strings, sorts them *as strings*, not as numbers. The following demonstrates why this is a problem:

```
>>> ', '.join(sorted([str(i) for i in range(67)]))
'0, 1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 2, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 3, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 4, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 5, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 6, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 7, 8, 9'
```

See how instead of `0, 1, 2` we get `0, 1, 10`? Similarly, we jump back to `2` between `19` and `20`; jump to `3` between `29` and `30`; `4` between `39` and `40`; etc. It's easy to see how this could look like jumping back to frame 1, even though that's not actually quite what it's doing.

---

You need to either pad your filenames so they all have the same number of digits (`001.png` instead of `1.png`), or tell Python to sort them numerically instead of as strings.

To do the latter, use the `key` argument to `sorted`, passing it as an argument a function that extracts the correct number. For example:

```
import os.path

def file_number(filename):
    return int(os.path.basename(filename).split('.')[0])

frames = sorted(glob.glob(str(frames_dir / '*.png')), key=file_number)
```

Comment: The video is now playing smoothly! Thank you so much! This makes so much more sense now.

Answer (score -1):

the issue is related that you are using `imshow` ,try this:

```py
import cv2
import glob
from pathlib import Path

def play_frames(frames_dir, fps, output_video_path):
    # Get the list of frames in the directory
    frames = sorted(glob.glob(str(frames_dir / '*.png')))

    # Read the first frame to get the width and height
    frame = cv2.imread(frames[0])
    height, width, _ = frame.shape

    # Create the video writer object
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
    video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(output_video_path, fourcc, fps, (width, height))

    for frame_path in frames:
        # Read the frame
        frame = cv2.imread(frame_path)

        # Write the frame to the video
        video_writer.write(frame)

    # Release the video writer
    video_writer.release()

# Directory path
frames_dir = Path('./detected_objects')
fps = 15
output_video_path = 'vid2output.mp4'

# Play the frames and save as video
play_frames(frames_dir, fps, output_video_path)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it still adds the first frame in every fps. It makes the video play choppy or unclean.

Comment: This _didn't actually fix the problem_, which had nothing at all to do with `imshow`. How is this upvoted?